# How does the roll period of dygraphs work?

Tags: r, dygraphs, moving-average

In [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-roll-periods.html) there is the official example of the roll periods function.

What is the function used ? (given N the roll period)

- With a simple moving average, the first N values should be NA, but they are not.
- There are 99 values, so if I put 99 as roll period, I thought I would have a straight line, but it is not.
- When I put 50 and 60, it seems that only values after the first 50 ones are changed.

Does anyone know the function, or how can I find it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a trailing average.

So if there are 100 values and you set 50 as the roll period, then:

- the first value will just be the first value
- the second will be the average of the first two
- ...
- the 50th will be the average of the first 50
- the 51st will be the average of values 2..51
- ...
- the 100th will be the average of values 51..100